# How can I make my dockerized Go program to use a dockerized Redis on default port?

Tags: unix, go, redis, docker

I have a Go program that uses a Redis client on it's default port 6379. I started a container from the official Redis image and I can see that it's working because redis-cli recognizes it, but the Go container cannot connect to it.

I also tried linking (after starting the Redis container) with

```
docker run --link redis:redis [APP_CONTAINER_NAME]
```

And I get the same result. The Go Redis client from my program is not able to see the Redis server.

Comment: `docker run ... [PROGRAM_NAME]`: Is `[PROGRAM_NAME]` the name of a docker image?

Comment: @VonC Yes. I used `docker build -t [APP_CONTAINER_NAME] .` to get my program's container. Then I started the Redis container and my program can't see the Redis server. After this I tried linking them with the above command.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/: `The --link flag will link the container named /redis into the newly created container with the alias redis. The new container can access the network and environment of the redis container via environment variables. ` Do you see those environmentvariables set in your program container?

Comment: As in https://www.orchardup.com/blog/docker-08: `$ orchard docker run --link redis:redis ubuntu env
REDIS_PORT=tcp://172.17.0.3:6379
REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP=tcp://172.17.0.3:6379
REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR=172.17.0.3
REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_PORT=6379
REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_PROTO=tcp`

Comment: what error are you getting? connection refused?

Comment: @booya Yes. It can't find a server on 6379 port.

Comment: @VonC My environment variables are `REDIS_PORT=tcp://127.0.0.1:6379
REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP=tcp://127.0.0.1:6379
REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_PORT=6379
`

Answer (score 0):

I the latest versions of docker, the linked container is available via DNS. Since you are using the default redis port you should be able to connect to redis using: redis://redis:6379